# How to use Dependency inject when using a service layer with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My project is an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. I am using Entity Framework Core and built-in dependency injection.

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
builder.Services.AddDbContext<myService>(options => options.UseSqlServer(ConnStr));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<anotherService>(options => options.UseSqlServer(anotherConnStr));
...
```

myController.cs:

```
public class myController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly myService _context;

    public myController(myService context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // ... Routes use either db models directly or methods from myService
}
```

myService.cs:

I'm using `myContext` as a base class so I can access the db tables directly in my controller.

Any better way to do this? db = this;

How do I inject this service?

```
private readonly anotherService anotherdb;
```

```
public class myService : myContext
{
    private readonly myContext db;
    private readonly anotherService anotherdb;

    public myService(DbContextOptions<myService> options) : base(options)
    {
        // inject myContext, works but doesn't feel right.
        db = this;
        
        // how do I inject this?
        anotherdb = new anotherService();
    }

    public IQueryable<mytable> Getdata()
    {
        var q = from s in db.mytable
                select s;

        return q;
    }
    // ...
}
```

myContext.cs:

```
public partial class myContext : DbContext
{
    public myContext()
    {
    }

    public myContext(DbContextOptions<myContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected myContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    // ...
}
```

I have lots of services all with the same design, how can I inject another service into `myService.cs`?

Comment: wouldn't you just add it to the constructor? `public myService(DbContextOptions<myService> options, anotherService otherService) ...`